# bat`ник для запуска по сети

Tags: cmd, bat

и выключения на нескольких ПК одного домена, выбранного процесса

Comment: http://comp0.ru/pstools.html#id5 оно?

Comment: сейчас попробую, спасибо

Comment: Читаем коротенький ман: `taskkill /?`